# Does the Volcker Rule apply to brokerage firms?

Tags: united-states, stocks, banking, trading, broker

The Volcker Rule states that it:

> prohibits any banking entity from engaging in proprietary trading or
>   from acquiring or retaining an ownership interest in, sponsoring, or
>   having certain relationships with a hedge fund or private equity fund 
>   (“covered fund”), subject to certain exemptions

Does this rule prohibit brokerage firms, or can they still engage in prop trading?

I am looking into several brokerage firms and would like to know what restrictions they face. (If brokerage firms within large banks are more regulated in terms of prop trading than smaller stand alone brokerage firms.)

Comment: Can you please clarify how this relates to personal finance? It's not immediately clear at the moment.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid a company that has a prop trading desk or find one?

Comment: @zeta-band can't you just assume they have a personal finance reason to ask this otherwise-valid-if-a-personal-reason-exists question?